# PHP Object Json encode to be decode by Android

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have  code in PHP

```
$avg_objs = $value['avg'];
```

I encode in Json and I get:

**"avg":23**

But I  need to get:

```
"avg":{"AverageTemperature":"23"}
```

Since I am using it to Android and if not get in this format I get and "org.json.JSONException: Response cannot be parsed as JSON data"

Thanks.

Comment: Both of them are not JSON.

Comment: It should be like this way : `{"avg":{"AverageTemperature":"23"}}`

Comment: Yes, I know it,I just have cutted some Json code. It comes from {....} ofcourse. I only wrote the Json Target data.

Comment: Perfection is the only key aspect point to be a programmer..! :D

Comment: Although without those curly braces your code won't work..! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP do

```
$json = array('avg' => array('AverageTemperature' => $value['avg']) );
$json_string = json_encode($json);
echo $json_string;
```

This will build the data structure you require, and `json_encode($json);` will ensure that a valid json string is created from it.